# How can I use align inside itemize without a newline?

Tags: lists, align, itemize

I would like to use `align` inside of `itemize` as an `item`, but without a newline. How can I do this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item ba dfasdfasd sadf
    \item asdfa sd $x^2$ asdfasdf
    \item \begin{align*}
                x^2 + 2x -10 &= 31\\
            \Leftrightarrow x^2 +2x + 21 &= 0\\
            \Leftrightarrow (x+1)^2+20 &= 0
          \end{align*}
    \item adfasd asdfas
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

It seems to me that there is also a newline after `align` or at least more whitespace than there should be. If it is possible, I would like to remove that, too.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate (so please close it; I've already voted for "close"). But I would never have found it with the other title.